# How to encrypt and decrypt string in separate method

Tags: groovy

I have a method that encrypts and then decrypts a string, but I need to encrypt and then decrypt the string in separate methods. So I have an error "**Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.**"

**It works perfectly**:

```
def encryptDecrypt(String password) {

    def key = "key0123456789".toCharArray()
    def salt = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,] as byte[]


    /* Derive the key, given password and salt. */
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(key, salt, 65536, 256);
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");


    /* Encrypt the message. */
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
    AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
    byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
    
    byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    logger.lifecycle("ciphertext:$ciphertext")
    
    def encryptedPassword = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ciphertext)
    logger.lifecycle("encryptedPassword:$encryptedPassword")

    def encryptedPasswordByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedPassword)
    logger.lifecycle("encryptedPasswordByte:$encryptedPasswordByte")

    /* Decrypt the message, given derived key and initialization vector. */
    Cipher cipherDecrypt = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipherDecrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    String plaintext = new String(cipherDecrypt.doFinal(encryptedPasswordByte), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    logger.lifecycle("--decryptedTRUE:$plaintext");
}
```

**This code throws the error mentioned above**

```
def encrypt(String encryptMe) {
    def key = "key0123456789".toCharArray()
    def salt = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,] as byte[]


    /* Derive the key, given password and salt. */
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(key, salt, 65536, 256);
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");


    /* Encrypt the message. */
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
    AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
    byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();

    byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(encryptMe.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    logger.lifecycle("ciphertext:$ciphertext")

    def encryptedPassword = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ciphertext)
    logger.lifecycle("encryptedPassword:$encryptedPassword")
    return encryptedPassword

}

def decrypt(String decryptMe) {
    def key = "key0123456789".toCharArray()
    def salt = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,] as byte[]

    /* Derive the key, given password and salt. */
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256")
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(key, salt, 65536, 256)
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec)
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES")
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret)
    AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters()
    byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV()

    def encryptedPasswordByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(decryptMe)
    logger.lifecycle("encryptedPasswordByte:$encryptedPasswordByte")

    /* Decrypt the message, given derived key and initialization vector. */
    Cipher cipherDecrypt = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipherDecrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv))
    String plaintext = new String(cipherDecrypt.doFinal(encryptedPasswordByte), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    logger.lifecycle("--decrypted:$plaintext");
    return plaintext
}
```

I read some topics in SO but I still don't have any idea where my mistake is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that your `def decrypt(String decryptMe)` method creates its own `byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV()`.

To properly decrypt the encrypted string it needs to know the `iv` that was used during encryption.

One way to solve this is to prepend the `iv` to the encrypted value:

```
def encrypt(String encryptMe) {
    //...
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(iv) + ":" + encryptedPassword
}

def decrypt(String decryptMe) {
    def parts = decryptMe.split(":")
    def iv = Base64.getDecoder().decode(parts[0))
    def encryptedPasswordByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(parts[1))
    //...
}
```